# How Unescape the already escaped string in kotlin?(Android)

Tags: string, kotlin

How to convert an **already Enscaped** string to unescape in android

```
// To convert from normal to enscaped string
val escaped:String = Regex.escape("")
```

but there is no Unescape function in [Regex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/escape.html)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you have an escaped string in the first place? Also what platform are you on?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry about that, i m trying to achieve local transmission using Sockets which is done already. now to avoid escape characters conflict in control statements i was converting to escaped string.

Comment: @AbdullahOmer but why do you use regex escaping? Are your control characters are same? Because regexp use funny way to escape special character. Make sure you want escaping made in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here example code that solve your problem:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val literal = "a\\Qb\\Ec"
    val str = Regex.escape(literal)

    val newValue = unescape(str)
    
    println(literal)
    println(str)
    println(newValue)
}

enum class S { BEGIN, ESC, LITERAL, ESC_END }

fun unescape(str: String): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    var state = S.BEGIN
    for (c in str.toCharArray()) {
        when (c) {
            '\\' ->
                when (state) {
                    S.BEGIN -> {
                        state = S.ESC
                    }

                    S.LITERAL -> {
                        state = S.ESC_END
                    }

                    S.ESC -> {
                        state = S.ESC
                        sb.append("\\")
                    }

                    S.ESC_END -> {
                        state = S.LITERAL
                        sb.append("\\\\")
                    }
                }

            'Q' ->
                when (state) {
                    S.ESC -> state = S.LITERAL
                    S.BEGIN -> {
                        sb.append(c)
                    }

                    S.LITERAL -> {
                        sb.append(c)
                    }

                    S.ESC_END -> {
                        state = S.LITERAL
                        sb.append("\\Q")
                    }
                }

            'E' ->
                when (state) {
                    S.ESC -> {
                        state = S.BEGIN
                        sb.append("E")
                    }
                    S.BEGIN -> {
                        sb.append(c)
                    }

                    S.LITERAL -> {
                        sb.append(c)
                    }

                    S.ESC_END -> {
                        state = S.BEGIN
                    }
                }

            else -> {
                sb.append(c)
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```